# ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock Object error

Tags: asp.net

I have created a variable in Javascript as Global. and I have initialized as object in initialize() function.

```
 var path;
 function initialize() {   
    var polyOptions = { strokeColor: '#FF0000', strokeOpacity: 1.0, strokeWeight: 2 }
    path = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
}

function drawpoly1() { 
path.getPath().push(location);
}
```

I am calling this function from .Net through

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock

Function is called but it shows the error as

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'path' is null or not an object

Please tell me how to handle this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi what i suggest is to call both the function from Server Side user ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock itself, because once you will postback your page you will lose the client scripts and it is obvious that you will not find the objects and definitions  you have declared client side. Example i have shown below may help you, try this:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  {    
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();    
    sb.Append("<script language='javascript'> var lbl; function Initialize() {");        
    sb.Append("lbl = 'lblDisplayDate';"); sb.Append("}</script>"); 

     if (!ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered("JSScriptBlock"))    {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "JSBlock", sb.ToString());   
           }

          string funcCall = "<script language='javascript'>Initialize();</script>"; 

          if (!ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("JSScript"))   { 
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "JSScript", funcCall);   
          }
   }
```